# How to validate AWS accesskey, secret key using c#

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Is there any way to verify AWS AccessKey, SecretKey are valid or not using c#?

```
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using Amazon.S3.IO;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Transfer;

AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(AccessKey, SecretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check it using try-catch with just a basic method like get bucket. If you a unable to get the bucket its mean you are not verified or the bucket not exist or another problem, But the fact is you can't access to your bucket

```
        AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(AccessKey, SecretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
        try
        {
            var buckets = s3Client.GetBucketLocationAsync("some-bucket").Result;
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception ex)
        {
              //do something when you can't access to your bucket
        }
```